# Join 2 variables when inserting from form

Tags: php, mysqli

Not sure how to figure this out! I am trying to create a schoolclass grading diagram. I have a table with 4 columns and 4 rows. Classes horizontal and student vertical.

The columns are genrated from db like this:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <?
        $query = "SELECT classname FROM class ORDER BY cname LIMIT 3";

        if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $classid = $row['classid'];
                echo '<th><div class="verticalText">'.$row['classname'].'</div></th>';
            }
        }
       ?> 
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Now, this is how I get the sudent vertical:

```
<tbody>
<?
$query = "SELECT studentid, studentname FROM students ORDER BY studentname";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        $studentid = $row['studentid'];

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td style="text-align:left;"><a href="#">'.$row["studentname"].'</a></td>';
        echo '<td>';
        echo '<input type="text" name="grade" id="grade" placeholder="--">';
        echo '</td>';   
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>  
</tbody>
</table>
<input type="submit" value="report" name="submit">
</form>
```

My question is. How do I on my insert.php get the classid and the studentid joined together so when I insert into the db I can tell what class and what grade each student has got?

Hope this makes any sense, and are looking forward to any answer.

Answer (score 0):

good question!

First, your class table will need autoincrementing id so you can get a clean reference to your class rows (referencing based on names is considered bad practice), after that you will need to add a 3rd table with 3 columns: class_id, student_id and grade. If you like you can add a combined primary key on student_id and class_id so the combination is forced to be unique. (I take it that is what you want)

This way of linking your data is called a relational database: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database

And this field setup is called a many-to-many-relationship: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)

```
// So your relational table will look like:
- student_id (part of primary key and foreign key that points to the student)
- class_id (part of primary key and foreign key that points to the class)
- grade
```

There is a lot to learn here, have a look at the articles and have a go. Good luck! :)